# Why does adding an edge to an empty graph not work as expected?

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 11.3**

---

Does anybody has an idea what is wrong with adding edge to an empty graph created by my custom function?

```
DiscreteGraph[n_]:=GraphComplement[CompleteGraph[n]];
EdgeAdd[DiscreteGraph[5],1<->2]
```

Note that the following works:

```
EdgeAdd[Graph[Range[5],{}],1<->2]
```

as well as the call with "graph-as-picture":

[image]

Comment: It's just one of the outrageous `Graph`-bugs that Wolfram hasn't fixed for years. I reported these types of failures multiple times.  [Please write to Wolfram Support and report it yourself.](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/)  The only way they'll do something about it is if more people report it.  Or maybe they've already abandoned all the `Graph` stuff!?  Sometimes I really have the impression that they did!!

Comment: The usual workaround to this kind of problem is to force the graph into another internal representation. There are many ways, such as `g = Uncompress@Compress[g]` or `g = Graph[VertexList[g],EdgeList[g]]` (loses properties). Then `EdgeAdd` won't fail.

Comment: Thanks for making clear the situation. Here I add another cherry at the tart top:

    `T=Graph[{1<->2,1<->3,3<->4,1<->5,5<->6,6<->7}]
    GraphAutomorphismGroup[T]`

Seems not to work in version 11.2, but works in version 10!!! (and yes, reported to company)

Comment: `GraphAutomorphismGroup[T]` works fine for me in 11.2 / OSX.  The function is known to be buggy on the Raspberry Pi, but AFAIK it works fine on desktop platforms.  The [IGraph/M package](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has a function you can use instead: `IGBlissAutomorphismGroup`.  Feel free to contact me with any feedback about this package (and please use the latest *pre*-release if you try it out).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug.

As a workaround, you can force Mathematica to change the internal representation of the graph by passing it through a compound expression representation in some manner.

For example,

```
g = Uncompress@Compress[g]
```

or

```
g = Graph[VertexList[g], EdgeList[g]] (* loses properties like EdgeWeight! *)
```

Alternatively, create the graph in an incidence representation directly:

```
emptyGraph[n_Integer?NonNegative] := Graph[Range[n], {}]
```